# Ячейка таблицы: высота и ширина

Tags: html, css

Как задать нужную высоту и ширину для отдельной ячейки таблицы?

Comment: может в гугл?..

Comment: ширина и длинна это в данном контексте разные вещи?) написал для ширины, про длину не учили =)

Answer (score 1):

```
<td style="width: 200px">123</td>
```

или

```
<style> td .pf { width: 100px;}</style>

<td class="pf" style="width: 200px">123</td>
```

Comment: @hashcode обратите внимание на последний участок кода, и попробуйте обрамить его как надо, у меня не получилось, пришлось извращаться..

Comment: А у меня получилось. `%)` Не забываем про магические 4 пробела

Comment: <td class="pf" style="width: 200px">123</td>

Comment: вот вам пожалуйста, 4 пробела ровно, результат виден.

Comment: В каментах они глючат, ибо текст сперва тримится, как я понял, потом обрабатывается

    123

Comment: я аналогично делал в ответе, та же история.

Comment: Значит, не аналогично. Все участки (цитаты, списки, код), кроме первого, отделяются пустым абзацм (`\n\n`). Так, на всякий случай) Это тоже есть в хелпе.

Comment: Изначально надо, сделать переход на другую строку, так чтобы между текстом и кодом была одна пустая строка:

    123

Answer (score 1):

если точнее 4 варианта))
но сначало: width - ширина(указывается в пикселах или %) height - высота(указывается так же)
1)

```
<td width="100px" height="100%">бла бла бла</td>
```

2)

```
<td style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">бла бла бла</td>
```

3)

```
<td class="name">style.css - td.name{width: 100%; height: 100px;}</td>
```

4)

```
<style>td.name { width: 100px; height: 100%;} </style>
<td class="name">бла бла бла</td>
```

вроде все варианты)))

Comment: `width="100px"` работать не будет. либо целое (`width="N"`), либо проценты (`width="N%"`)

Comment: мнда, действительно, голова щас жестоко забита пхп, никак не могу один креатив заставить работать:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td width="100" height="100">text</td>
```

Comment: Я не хочу спорить. Смахивает на совок: жить стало легче, жить стало веселей. Все отлично, багов нет? вопросов нет.

Comment: Я ж как бы не спорю, что баги есть, поддержу любое начинание в их репортинге и хантинге) Просто если что-то сделано, скажем, не идеально, это не значит, что дело в самой идее.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="100" height="80"></td>
<td width="50" height="20" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

как видно ключевое свойство display:block, для ячейки размер которой должен быть независимым от общей высоты и ширины столбца или строки.